# Unable to fetch Data in Netlify Dev Proxy (React)

Tags: reactjs, netlify, netlify-function

I've been having CORS error when deploying my app so I decided to try out Netlify Dev.

I followed all steps of the written tutorials but I keep getting errors without being able to identify whats wrong. I haven't even deployed it yet and right now I am having the 403 error, before this was the 500 internal server error.

Please let me know if you notice any obvious mistake on my part.

Here's the node-fetch code:

```
const fetch = require("node-fetch");
exports.handler = async function () {
  const headers = {
    "x-api-key": process.env.REACT_APP_MY_API_KEY,
    "content-type": "application/json",
  };
  try {
    const response = await fetch("https://api.crimeometer.com", { headers });
    if (!response.ok) {
      return { statusCode: response.status, body: response.statusText };
    }
    const data = await response.json();

    return {
      statusCode: 200,
      body: JSON.stringify(data),
    };
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return {
      statusCode: 500,
      body: JSON.stringify({ msg: err.message }),
    };
  }
};
```

Here's the frontend of my app (with the relevant code):

```
  const initializeApp = useCallback(() => {

    async function fetchData() {
      try {
        let req = new Request(
          `./.netlify/functions/node-fetch?lat=${lat}&lon=${lon}&distance=10km&datetime_ini=${newdateyear}&datetime_end=${newdatenow}&page=1`);
        const res = await fetch(req);
        const info = await res.json();

        setCrimes(info.incidents);

      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    }

  }, [submit, lat, lon]);

  useEffect(() => {
    initializeApp();
  }, [initializeApp]);
```

This is the error in my console:
[image]

This is where i am trying to fetch data from:

```
https://api.crimeometer.com/v1/incidents/raw-data?lat=${lat}&lon=${lon}&distance=10km&datetime_ini=${newdateyear}&datetime_end=${newdatenow}&page=1

It requires two headers to be set on frontend, which I have done in the netlify function
```

Comment: https://api.crimeometer.com/v1/incidents/raw-data returns forbidden by default. I guess you suppose to have some auth header for it

Comment: I've been fetching data from this api normally on my react app. I had CORS issue locally once. But that was resolved now I can fetch without an issue. Only when I try to deploy to netlify I get the cors error again. Thus i was trying to use netlify functions to work around it

Answer (score 0):

The API key is currently being added to the React side, where it sets a header and makes a call to the netlify function. But the API key is actually required at the netlify function to request the third party API.

So you have to move the request header from React to Netlify function with something like:

```
const headers = {
  'x-api-key': API_KEY,
  'content-type': 'application/json',
}

const response = await fetch(
   "https://api.crimeometer.com/v1/incidents/raw-data",
   { headers }
);
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer! 

So did you mean to name this constant Headers? 'const Headers = require('node-fetch');'

Also I removed the headers from the React side and added them on the function. 
Which now returns a 500 (internal server error)

Comment: Sorry, had copied that from their docs, but now that I read it definitely looks off, can you try the edit @parsa

Comment: Sorry, had copied that from their docs, but now that I read it definitely looks off, can you try the edit @parsa

Comment: Yes Agney I did put the headers in the function and removed from React side and it gives me a 500 internal error. Do you need to see anymore code? This is my first time using Netlify functions so I really don't have a clue what the issue is

Comment: @Parsa Can you add your current function code to the question?

Comment: @Parsa It seems you are still using `Headers` constructor, can you try this as in my answer

Comment: *embarassing* Sorry just updated it correctly now, doing it exactly like you did. But the 500 error is still there :(

Comment: Is there an error message with the 500? Are you sure API_KEY is available?

Comment: oh because of the copy pasting I messed up the API_KEY, it should be process.env.REACT_APP_MY_API_KEY. Okay updated that. 

Now i am back to my old 403 forbidden error
SyntaxError: Unexpected token F in JSON at position 0

Comment: I'm wordering if the env key is available in Netlify fn. can you try hardcoding the API key?

Comment: i did make it available in functions and also in the .env.development file in my react root